# How to exclude certain files from being piped to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, glob, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Given that I have the following files.

1. /tmp/example.txt
2. /tmp/example.txt_<date> (e.g. /tmp/example.txt_20230207)
3. /tmp/example.txt.lck

I want to pipe example.txt and /tmp/example.txt_<date> to CloudWatch and exclude example.txt.lck.

Following Glob syntax (as mentioned in the official document that it uses Glob), "/tmp/example.txt*(!(.lck))" should do the trick. (tested on [DigitalOcean's online Glob tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt%2A%28%21%28.lck%29%29&matches=false&tests=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt&tests=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt_20230207&tests=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt_20230208&tests=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt_20230208&tests=%2Ftmp%2Fexample.txt.lck))

However, when applied the configuration, it is not sending any of the above files to CloudWatch.

Is there any other methods or alternative to achieve the result?

I have tested with /tmp/example.txt* and it works, but it is **sending all 3 files**. So at the very least, I know that my CloudWatch Agent is working.

It is quite likely a mistake in my glob expression or it might not be supported at the moment (as we can see from this issue - https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/issues/328, "alternative brackets" (i.e. {}) is not supported, hence chances are I'm using unsupported glob expression too).

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax should be:

```
"/tmp/example.txt*[!(.lck)]"
```

If this doesn't work, you can hack your way around this by excluding "k" as the last character in the string.

```
"/tmp/example.txt*[!k]"
```

Or you can include the files separately in the config as follows:

```
"logs_collected": {
           "files": {
               "collect_list": [
                   {
                       "file_path": "/tmp/example.txt_20230207",
                       "log_group_name": "",
                       "log_stream_name": "",
                       "timestamp_format": ""
                   },
                   {
                       "file_path": "/tmp/example.txt",
                       "log_group_name": "",
                       "log_stream_name": ""
                   }
               ]
           },
```